# error 404 Not Found: @ionic/cli-utils@1.13.1 during npm install

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, artifactory, npm-install

After installing cordova using

```
npm install cordova -g
```

I tried to install ionic, using

```
npm install ionic -g
```

but got

> 404 Not Found: @ionic/cli-utils@1.13.1

combining both statements as

```
npm install cordova ionic -g
```

generates the same error.

What could be the problem here? I use Artifactory as node modules proxy by the way, which generally works well in my environment.

Comment: what is npm version?

Comment: The version is 5.3.0

Comment: related? https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2466

Comment: Yes, but unsolved.

Comment: maybe try the last comment of setting registry

Comment: I cannot do this, since I need to use the npm-artifactory settings.

Comment: what do you see in the Artifactory logs? (request.log and artifactory.log)